# Xcode Scene Graph Pyramid Size

Tags: xcode, scenekit, arkit

When adding a pyramid from the objects library to the scene graph, the objects appears, but the size shown in the attributes inspector is 0 for height, width and length.  When I attempt to change the 0 to 1 or 0.5, the size changes back to 0 when my cursor exits the size box and makes the pyramid disappear.

All other shapes are fine - and I can create the pyramid programmatically - just not in the scene graph.

Note - the "arrow" in the screenshot is just an empty node

Is there a way I can alter the pyramid size in the scene graph?

[screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3yVd.jpg)

Comment: instead of attribute inspector go to node inspector and change the scale. i didnt know this case exists as I have always used scale to resize

Comment: @AlokSubedi That did it!  Going through a couple of SceneKit tutorials and they changed the size directly-was so confused when mine vanished.  Thanks for the help!